# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector in C linux Error

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

This is a code to initialize a 2D array of chars in C
The array is 3X3 of characters
I'm using Eclipse C/C++ IDE for ubuntu
and when using this function GCC outputs an error like this:

***subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector***

what does tis error means ,can any one help me please , thanks in advance :)

```
void init(char* ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            *ptr[i][j]=' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be defined as `char** ptr` the argument of `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

ou are passing just a single pointer in init. If it is 3x3, then you'll need to change your signature to:

```
 void init(char **ptr){ ... }
```

And when accessing your pointer, either:

```
ptr[i][j] = '';
```

or

```
(*(ptr[i])+j) = '';
```

or

```
(*(*(ptr+i))+j) = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is a `pointer` to `char` not `char[][]` . so you should use `**ptr` or `char (*ptr)[size_of_2nd_dimension]`

or simple:

```
void init(char (*ptr)[size2]) <-----
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j]=' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can't guess the size of the array, but since it's `c` you can do the manipulation yourself (2 options):

```
void initA(char* ptr, int totalSize)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
    {
        *ptr[i]=' ';
    }
}

void initB(char* ptr, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<sizeX;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeY;j++)
        {
            *ptr[(i * sizeY) + j]=' ';
        }
    }
}
```